# How set the value kCFCalendarUnitWeekday

Tags: iphone, notifications, scheduled-tasks

i want to set the value kCFCalendarUnitWeekday by using button and these value can pass the notification . I want to set alarm a particular day for eg. (mon,tue,sat for every week).

Answer (score 0):

`kCFCalendarUnitWeekday` is a [constant](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFCalendarRef/Reference/reference.html) that you *should not modify*. I don't quite understand what you want to do, but it sounds like you should take a look at [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Comment: Thank u for answer my question. but i want to set notification having different dates eg (sun, wed, fri, sat etc) at a same time in one notification. it is possible...

Comment: @Rahul Salvikar: You'll have to elaborate a bit more, or even better, post code. If you're trying to create something like the iPhone's built-in alarm, you could be interested in [recurrence rules](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2445#section-4.8.5). But in the end, you're most probably going to use `NSDate`s, `NSTimer`s, etc...